# SwiftUI is it possible to pass range of binding in ForEach?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'd like to pass a range of an array in a model inside ForEach.

I recreated an example:

```
import SwiftUI

class TheModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var list: [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
}

struct MainView: View {
    @StateObject var model = TheModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach (0...1, id:\.self) { item in
                SubView(subList: $model.list[0..<5])  <-- error if I put a range                    
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    @Binding var subList: [Int]
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach (subList, id:\.self) { item in
                Text("\(item)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainView()
    }
}
```

> **The work around**

I found is to pass all the list and perform the range inside the subView. But I'd like don't do this because the array is very big:

```
struct MainView: View {
@StateObject var model = TheModel()
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach (0...1, id:\.self) { i in
            SubView(subList: $model.list, number: i, dimension: 5)
        }
    }
}
}

struct SubView: View {
    @Binding var subList: [Int]
    var number: Int
    var dimension: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach (subList[number*dimension..<dimension*(number+1)].indices, id:\.self) { idx in
                Button(action: {
                    subList[idx] += 1
                    print(subList)
                }, label: {
                    Text("num: \(subList[idx])")
                })
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `SubView.subList` a binding? Can `SubView` somehow change the array given to it, and you want the change to reflect in `TheModel.list`?

Comment: @Sweeper yes it is, in the work around I insert a button like an example to change an item

Comment: Oh right. I didn't read your workaround code too much, and thought they are the same, haha

Comment: Note that you can't mutate the original array through the `ArraySlice` you got from `list[0..<5]`, even without this SwiftUI stuff. So my idea would be to write your own reference type that wraps an array, that you can pass to the subview, without copying the whole array this time.

Comment: @Sweeper could you write in code your idea? :)

Comment: What about sending the model property as one argument and the range as another to the sub view?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson something like my work around?

Comment: Yes but only the model itself since it is passed by reference. Or you might want to research how to best handle a StateObject in this situation, I am unsure about that.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I thought also to pass model as "@"EnviromentObject, but I'me not sure if is changing something in performance speaking

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the model to the subview since it is a class and will be passed by reference and then pass the range as a separate parameter.

Here is my new implementation of SubView

```
struct SubView: View {
    var model: TheModel
    var range: Range<Int>
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach (model.list[range].indices, id:\.self) { idx in
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        model.list[idx] += 1
                        print(model.list)
                    }, label: {
                        Text("num: \(model.list[idx])")
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I added `indices` to the `ForEach` header to make sure we access the array using an index and not with a value from the array.

The calling view would then look like

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        SubView(model: model, range: (0..<5))
        Text("\(model.list.map(String.init).joined(separator: "-"))")
    }
```

The extra `Text` is just there for testing purposes

Comment: so no way to pass only a part of the array?

Comment: You can but then you must have code to update the array in the model with the changes, I can't see how that would be simpler